# Investigating context changes triggered by function calls in tasks

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await, concurrency, task

I'm curious about why *Task C* and *Task D* are not executed on the main thread, unlike *Task A* and *Task B*. I comprehend that tasks inherit context from their parent, and in this case, they all share the same parent. Could it be assumed that the calling function results in the creation of *detached* tasks?

```
struct ThreadTestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test Thread")
            .onAppear {
                // Task A
                print("Task A - \(threadInfo())")
                
                // Task B
                Task {
                    print("Task B - \(threadInfo())")
                }
                
                // Task C
                printInfo("Task C")
                
                // Task D
                Task {
                    printInfo("Task D")
                }
            }
    }
    
    func printInfo(_ source: String) {
        Task {
            print("\(source) - \(threadInfo())")
        }
        // detached
        Task.detached {
            print("\(source) - detached \(threadInfo())")
        }
    }
    
    func threadInfo() -> String {
        "isMain:\(Thread.isMainThread) - \(Thread.current)"
    }
}

#Preview {
    ThreadTestView()
}
```

console output:

```
Task A - isMain:true - <_NSMainThread: 0x280694040>{number = 1, name = main}
Task C - isMain:false - <NSThread: 0x2806c6b00>{number = 8, name = (null)}
Task C - detached isMain:false - <NSThread: 0x2806c4580>{number = 5, name = (null)}
Task B - isMain:true - <_NSMainThread: 0x280694040>{number = 1, name = main}
Task D - isMain:false - <NSThread: 0x2806c6b00>{number = 8, name = (null)}
Task D - detached isMain:false - <NSThread: 0x2806c6b00>{number = 8, name = (null)}
```

Comment: You have nothing in your code to require execution on the main thread so Swift is free to use any thread it likes. There is little value in "investigating" behaviour that could change. If you need something to execute on the main thread then you should enforce that appropriately. If you don't need something to be on the main thread then let Swift handle it.

Comment: An actor only guarantees that the async/await function will return to the parent’s actor it does not guarantee that the function will be executed in the parent actor. The whole point of the new concurrency is to let actors decide where the work is done.

Comment: FYI it's `.task { }` in SwiftUI, not `Task { }`

Comment: @malhal It's effectively the same, just that the `.task { }` modifier automatically wires up the cancellation behaviour.

Comment: I suspect that malhal was encouraging future readers to avoid unnecessary unstructured concurrency.

Comment: Fair, and I agree with that. I was trying to highlight that these aren't competing technologies, as with say Tasks vs DispatchQueues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my understanding. Will be happy to correct/improve it if anyone has a deeper understanding of what's going on.

Your View (`struct ThreadTestView: View`) is not annotated as `@MainActor`. Protocol View itself is not annotated with `@MainActor` either. Only `body` inside `protocol View` is annotated with `@MainActor`:

> `@ViewBuilder @MainActor var body: Self.Body { get }`

So I think the behavior derives from those 3 facts.

First of all we should monitor not only tasks spawned in `printInfo`, but also where the function itself is called:

```
func printInfo(_ source: String) {
        
        // THIS: where the function itself is called
        print("\(source) - function itself \(threadInfo())")
        
        Task {
            print("\(source) - \(threadInfo())")
        }
        // detached
        Task.detached {
            print("\(source) - detached \(threadInfo())")
        }
    }
```

So what do I expect here:

- function `printInfo` itself (the new line I added above) will be called on main thread in all 4 cases. This is because all the items that have `body` as a parent (which is annotated with `@MainActor`) will keep that context.
- In case C the Task is spawned from `printInfo`, which is not, as we established, a @MainActor. Hence that Task is not a main actor either.
- In case D first Task is spawned from inside the `body`, and it will inherit the main actor context (so function `printBody` will run on main thread) - much like case B. But the second Task is spawned from the function `printInfo` will not be on main thread, like case C.

I agree that cases C and D are confusing. Some good discussion about these limitations [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/actor-inheritance-when-spawning-task-indirectly-via-synchronous-non-isolated-function/61429) and [here](https://oleb.net/2022/swiftui-task-mainactor/)

Answer (score 3):

A and B are on the main thread because [`body`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/body-8kl5o) is isolated to the main actor (and therefore runs on the main thread). Obviously A would therefore run on the main thread. And B launches `Task {…}` unstructured concurrency, which creates a new top-level task on the current actor (i.e., the main actor in this case), so it, too, runs on the main thread.

C and D are not on the main thread, however, because `printInfo` is not actor-isolated, and as such, however you initiate the unstructured concurrency, the resulting task is not actor-isolated, either. So, the tasks created by `printInfo` run on threads from the cooperative thread pool, not the main thread.

---

If `printInfo` method was isolated to the main actor (either explicitly prefixed with `@MainActor` itself, or was a member of a type which was isolated to the main actor along with all of its members), the story would change. Then its `Task {…}` would be isolated to the same actor, while `Task.detached {…}` still would not be isolated to any actor and thus would run on a random thread from the cooperative thread pool.

Comment: While I have attempted to answer your questions about whether code runs on the main thread or not, it really is best to stop worrying about which thread something is on, and instead focus on whether it is actor-isolated or not, and if so, which actor.

Answer (score 0):

> Huge disclaimer: I am still in the process of filling in my own gaps in understanding of Swift Concurrency, so I'm happy to be proven wrong on any of the following statements.

I think the important takeaway here is that the "main thread" is not the same thing as the "main actor." There are several differences between the two, but one notable difference is that actors are a compile-time construct, and threads are mostly a runtime one. Just because code is running on the main thread does not mean that it is "main-actor-isolated." Looking at the documentation for the [onAppear(perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onappear(perform:)) method, you can see that the `perform` closure does not include the `@MainActor` annotation, so it is not main-actor-isolated, though we can be pretty confident that it will be called on the main thread. Therefore, when you instantiate a `Task` from inside this closure—despite the fact that `Task.init` inherits the current actor—the closure itself is not actor-isolated, so there's no actor to inherit. The executor is free to schedule this task on any thread that becomes available in the cooperative thread pool, or even on the main thread it would seem. Try annotating your `printInfo` function with `@MainActor` to see how things change.

Comment: You are correct that there is a difference between main actor and main thread. But `.onAppear` *is* isolated to the main actor, despite the absence of an explicit `@MainActor` qualifier on the closure. This is illustrated by OP’s example, where B runs on the main actor. Or try calling functions isolated to main actor vs another global actor from within `.onAppear`, and empirically you can see that it most definitely is isolated to the main actor. It's not clear to me how (beyond the fact that `body` is isolated to the main actor), but it is.

Comment: Another weird example: `DispatchQueue.main.async {…}` is isolated to the main actor, too, despite any `@MainActor` qualifier. But,`let queue = DispatchQueue.main` followed by `queue.async {…}` is *not.* It looks like they’re doing some sleight of hand behind the scenes to reduce main actor friction for us. The documentation is sorely lacking here…